# Insert vector into matrix at specific columns

Tags: matrix, fortran, gfortran

How would I insert a vector b into a matrix at column col? I cannot find any syntax for and insert or append function in Fortran.

So far all I have done is reassigned the values in the column, but I only want to insert the vector.

```
real :: M(n,n)
integer :: n, col 
real :: b(n)
M(n:col) = b(:)
```

Comment: So when I understand it correctly you want to insert the vector `b` in the matrix `M` where `M` is of size  `nxn` and `b` of size `n`. Assuming that n <= col: `M(:,col) = b` or `M(1:n,col) = b(1:n)`

Comment: @albert, I guess OP is trying to increase one dimension of matrix M by one then literally insert vector b at the column with index col, right-shifting all columns from indices col,..,n to col+1,...,n+1, making room for b. Is it right?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues might be the case but is not 100% clear to me from the question. In that case we need to know how OP declared the `M` matrix, OP please supply the details, read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood of your problem, you want to:

- increase the number `n` of columns of the matrix `m` by 1;
- insert the content of a vector `b` in `m` as a new column, at index `col`;
- right-shift the remaining columns of `m`, in order to not lose any data.

Being this the case, you will need a couple of things:

- matrix `m` must be `allocatable` if you want to update the data locally. If you want to return a new independent array as a result, this wouldn't be necessary (but an additional data copy would be made).
- better use a compiler at least 2003 standard compliant so you have access to the intrinsic `move_alloc`, that avoid one array copy in the redimension.

Here is a demo implementation:

```
program insert_vec
  integer, allocatable :: m(:, :), b(:)
  integer :: n = 3, col = 2, i
  allocate(m(n, n))
  allocate(b(n))
  m = 10
  b = [(i, i = 1, n)]
  call insert(m, b, col)
  do i = 1, n
      print *, m(i, :)
  end do
contains
  subroutine insert(m, b, col)
    integer, allocatable, intent(inout) :: m(:, :)
    integer, intent(in) :: b(size(m, 1)), col
    integer, allocatable :: temp(:, :)
    integer :: rows, cols
    rows = size(m, 1)
    cols = size(m, 2)
    allocate(temp(rows, cols + 1))
    temp(:, 1:col) = m(:, 1:col)
    temp(:, col) = b
    temp(:, col + 1:cols + 1) = m(:, col:cols)
    call move_alloc(temp, m)
  end
end
```

My output with [gfortran 7.1.1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php) is:

```
      10           1          10          10
      10           2          10          10
      10           3          10          10
```